# Send f.select parameter to jquery and show dynamic form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I have a form who uses a nasted form. I want to him show up when the f.select selects the option unificação.

I using a example that i see in a example, when i select a new option the alert appers, but i don't know how i send the selected element to function and how i tell to him to show the f.fields_for :unifications.

```
<div class="form-row">
    <label>
        <span>Evento</span>
            <%= f.select :event, ['Reencaminhar', 'Reclassificar', 'Rejeitar alteracão de diagnóstico', 'Rejeitar reencaminhamento', 'Solicitar esclarecimento', 'Cancelar solicitação', 'Rejeitar cancelamento', 'Responder', 'Unificação', 'Envio de cópia de ID', 'Reiterar', 'Registrar Solicitação', 'Reabrir solicitação', 'Complementar solicitação'], {}, :onChange => "fillForm.test(this)" %>
    </label>      

</div>

<%= f.fields_for :unifications do |unification_form| %>
    <label>
        <%= unification_form.link_to_remove "Remover cpf" %>
        <%= unification_form.text_field :cpf %>      
    </label>
<% end %>

requests.coffee 

@fillForm =
    test: ->
        alert('Hello world')
```

Comment: Eduardo, your question is not clear. Could you please provide all the HTML, form included? Do you want to select your event and immediately send the result to the server, how does it works?

Comment: No, i want to select a option, and if the option is equals to Unificação the f.fields_for :unification appear in the screen. This code only print hello world in the screen when i change the f.select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a div to hide/show the nested form block:

```
<div id="attributes-to-display" style="display:none">
  <%= f.fields_for :unifications do |unification_form| %>
    <label>
      <%= unification_form.link_to_remove "Remover cpf" %>
      <%= unification_form.text_field :cpf %>      
    </label>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Its hidden by default. I don't use coffee script, so a possible solution with plain javascript:

```
// binds the change event
$("#the_select_id").on('change', function() {
  // checks if the selected value is what you expect
  if ($(this).val() == "whatever") {
    // if so, show the block
    $("#attributes-to-display").show();
  }
  else {
    // if not, hide the block
    $("#attributes-to-display").hide();
    // and clean the cpf input box
    $("#the_nested_input_id").val('');
  }
});
```

You need to replace the ids (#) with the correct form ids, as I don't have enough information to provide it.

Comment: Thanks, man. It Works!!

I only change one thing, in the div i put hidden="true" instead style="display:none"